# Accessing internally stored media files - MediaPlayer on Android

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play a file in internal storage with `MediaPlayer` and am unable to do so. The initialization sequence fails on the `setDataSource` part. The code I am using:

```
public class HelloMediaPlayer extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mp = null;
    private Button play;
    private boolean isPrepared = false;
    private String fileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_media_player);

        //init mediaplayer.
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.i(this.toString(), "Mediaplayer prepared.");
                isPrepared = true;
            }
        });

        fileName = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/word_recorded.wav"; 
        //fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/word.wav";
        Log.v(this.toString(), "filename = " + fileName);
        File file = new File(fileName);
        String str = file.getName();
        Log.v(this.toString(), "file name = " + str);
        if(file.exists()) {
            if(file.canRead()) {
                Log.v(this.toString(), fileName + " exists and can be read.");
            } else {
                Log.e(this.toString(), fileName + " exists but cannot be read.");
                if(file.setReadable(true, false)) {
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Changed permissions on " + file.getName());
                } else {
                    Log.e(this.toString(), "Failed to set permissions either.");
                    Log.e(this.toString(), "Attempting to copy into another file.");

                    try {
                        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("word_recorded2.wav", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                        InputStream is = openFileInput("word_recorded.wav");

                        //copy data.
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                        int length = 0;
                        try {
                            while((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                            }
                            fos.flush();
                            fos.close();
                            is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.v(this.toString(), "Copied file name.");                        
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(this.toString(), fileName + " does not exist.");
        }

        try {
            //mp.setDataSource(openFileInput(str).getFD());
            mp.setDataSource(fileName);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.v(this.toString(), "Data source set to: " + fileName);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        Log.v(this.toString(), "Audio stream for mp set.");
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v(this.toString(), "Clicked Play button.");
                if(isPrepared) {
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Mediaplayer is prepared.");
                    mp.start();
                } else {
                    Log.e(this.toString(), "mediaplayer is not prepared.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hello_media_player, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The `LogCat` messages:

```
10-27 10:23:31.630: V/com.sriram.hellomediaplayer.HelloMediaPlayer@410690f0(19317): file name = word_recorded.wav
10-27 10:23:31.640: E/com.sriram.hellomediaplayer.HelloMediaPlayer@410690f0(19317): /data/data/com.sriram.hellomediaplayer/files/word_recorded.wav exists but cannot be read.
10-27 10:23:31.640: E/com.sriram.hellomediaplayer.HelloMediaPlayer@410690f0(19317): Failed to set permissions either.
10-27 10:23:31.650: E/com.sriram.hellomediaplayer.HelloMediaPlayer@410690f0(19317): Attempting to copy into another file.
10-27 10:23:31.650: W/System.err(19317): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sriram.hellomediaplayer/files/word_recorded.wav: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
10-27 10:23:31.650: W/System.err(19317):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
10-27 10:23:31.650: W/System.err(19317):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
10-27 10:23:31.650: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:610)
10-27 10:23:31.660: W/System.err(19317):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:159)
10-27 10:23:31.660: W/System.err(19317):    at com.sriram.hellomediaplayer.HelloMediaPlayer.onCreate(HelloMediaPlayer.java:65)
10-27 10:23:31.660: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-27 10:23:31.660: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-27 10:23:31.660: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
10-27 10:23:31.670: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-27 10:23:31.670: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-27 10:23:31.670: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-27 10:23:31.670: W/System.err(19317):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 10:23:31.670: W/System.err(19317):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 10:23:31.670: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-27 10:23:31.670: W/System.err(19317):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 10:23:31.680: W/System.err(19317):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 10:23:31.680: W/System.err(19317):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-27 10:23:31.680: W/System.err(19317):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-27 10:23:31.680: W/System.err(19317):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 10:23:31.680: W/System.err(19317): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
10-27 10:23:31.690: W/System.err(19317):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
10-27 10:23:31.690: W/System.err(19317):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
10-27 10:23:31.690: W/System.err(19317):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
10-27 10:23:31.690: W/System.err(19317):    ... 18 more
10-27 10:23:31.700: V/com.sriram.hellomediaplayer.HelloMediaPlayer@410690f0(19317): Data source set to: /data/data/com.sriram.hellomediaplayer/files/word_recorded.wav
10-27 10:23:31.700: V/com.sriram.hellomediaplayer.HelloMediaPlayer@410690f0(19317): Audio stream for mp set.
10-27 10:23:31.700: I/MediaPlayer(19317): ======>prepare
10-27 10:23:31.700: I/MediaPlayer(19317): ======>prepareAsync_l
10-27 10:23:31.720: E/MediaPlayer(19317): error (1, -2147483648)
10-27 10:23:31.720: W/System.err(19317): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
10-27 10:23:31.720: W/System.err(19317):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
10-27 10:23:31.720: W/System.err(19317):    at com.sriram.hellomediaplayer.HelloMediaPlayer.onCreate(HelloMediaPlayer.java:113)
10-27 10:23:31.720: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-27 10:23:31.720: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-27 10:23:31.720: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
10-27 10:23:31.720: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-27 10:23:31.720: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-27 10:23:31.720: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-27 10:23:31.720: W/System.err(19317):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 10:23:31.730: W/System.err(19317):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 10:23:31.730: W/System.err(19317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-27 10:23:31.730: W/System.err(19317):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 10:23:31.730: W/System.err(19317):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 10:23:31.730: W/System.err(19317):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-27 10:23:31.730: W/System.err(19317):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-27 10:23:31.740: W/System.err(19317):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 10:23:31.820: D/libEGL(19317): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
10-27 10:23:31.830: D/libEGL(19317): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_VIVANTE.so
10-27 10:23:31.840: D/libEGL(19317): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_VIVANTE.so
10-27 10:23:31.860: D/libEGL(19317): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_VIVANTE.so
10-27 10:23:31.900: D/OpenGLRenderer(19317): Enabling debug mode 0
```

What I have tried so far:
1. Changed permissions on the file stored internally with `file.setReadable`. The command fails to set `WORLD_READABLE` permissions.
2. Tried to copy it into another file which was created specifically with `WORLD_READABLE and WORLD_WRITEABLE` permissions. Oddly, I get a `FileNotFound` error despite the previous lines saying that the file `word_recorded.wav` was present.
3. The permissions on word_recorded.wav suggest that the file is readable but the program indicates otherwise.
4. Pulled the wav file out and played it on my system. It plays just fine.
5. Passed a `FileDescriptor` to the program. This has not worked either.

My question(s):
1. Where am I going wrong? How do I make this work?

Comment: How did the file get to the app data directory? Why not simply put it in the raw resource directory? If you really want it to work from where it's at, what are the owner, group, and permissions when you look at the file through adb shell?

Comment: The file was generated by a TTS engine. I cannot put it in the raw resource directory because it is not static - each time the user decides to have the TTS engine speak something, the file word.wav is over-written. The files permissions are `rw` for everyone.

Comment: I've also seen this (on a GT-I9300-SDK15), but with an XML file. However, this is very rare. Maybe one time in thousands of users.

Answer (score 1):

```
10-27 10:23:31.680: W/System.err(19317): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Do you have the the permission to read file from internal storage ?

Comment: and what permission is that?

Comment: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maybe ?

Comment: There are no permissions required to read from internal storage. Internal storage is a private storage area that is specific to each app. `Read_External_Storage` refers to SD cards and the like.

Comment: Did you ever end up finding the solution?